# Initialize a char array or string with a pointer in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I have a pointer, where the next **`X`** elements are *ASCII* characters with a `'\0'` at the end. I need to save the *ASCII* characters either in a `char` array or `string` type.

Is it possible to dynamically initialize a `string` or `char` array in `C++` with a pointer?
The code below does not compile with the following error:

```
char symbol[11];
symbol = (packet+8);
```

> error: array type 'char [11]' is not assignable

(`packet` is a pointer that holds the data and the *ASCII* characters start at the 8th location).

Ideally, I would like to avoid having to iterate through the pointer to initialize the string or character array.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
    symbol[i] = *(packet+8+i);
}
```

Thank you in advance for all the help.

Comment: What is `packet`?

Comment: You can't assign a c-string. you can assign a `std::string`

Comment: `std::string symbol = packet + 8;` should work fine. Or if `packet` is not NUL-terminated, then `std::string symbol(packet + 8, 11);`

Comment: @KorelK packet is a const u_char*.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I get the following error: no viable conversion from 'const u_char *' (aka 'const unsigned char *') to 'std::string' . Packet is of type const u_char*

Comment: `std::string symbol = (char*)packet + 8;`, then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`std::copy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) to copy the contents like this:

```
char symbol[11];
std::copy(packet + 8, packet + 19, symbol);
```

or use a `std::string` constructor:

```
std::string symbol(packet + 8, packet + 19);
```